# How to to find if device orientation is same as screen orientration

Tags: android

With

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I can find the orientation of my layout.  Now I want to lock my layout in some orientation e.g `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);` and to find real phone orientation (layout is set to portrait, but user for some reason holds his device in landscape)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options.

- Use config changes:

> Manifiest

```
<activity android:name=".HelloAndroid"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:configChanges="orientation">
```

> In your code

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
    // TODO
}
```

You have to override this method.

- Use an [OrientationEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html), which has a method called onOrientationChanged.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) is a good Handling Runtime Changes tutorial.

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
if (this.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
     .getOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
     // portrait mode
} else if (this.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
     .getOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
     // landscape
}
```

I have tested this way and it works for me.

Comment: Hello. I probably formed my question bad. Your part about onConfigurationChanged is shown in my topic. Basicly the main question is: How to to find if device orientation is same as screen orientration/

Comment: @Yarh I guess for finding out the actual position of the device you should be using gyroscope

Comment: @Yarh post has been edited. The new way works for me

Comment: info about OrientationEventListener helped me, other is not relative to my problem